# Adding LIMIT with query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a problem with this query I want retrieve all records but leaving first twenty,

Error is: {"Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'."}

```
"SELECT * FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + country.Text + "' ORDER BY [upload_time] DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `LIMIT` with SQL Server. You can use [`Top 20`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx). Or you can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and then filter based on that.

Also you should [parametrized your query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx), your current query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TOP 20 * 
                                         FROM [upload_news] 
                                         WHERE [country]=@country ORDER BY [upload_time] DESC", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country.Text);
    //,.... rest of the code
}
```

Comment: +1 for offering an option that isn't hideously vulnerable to injection.

Answer (score 2):

If it's SQL Server, you need to use Top N.

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + country.Text + "'
ORDER BY [upload_time] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retrieve all records but leaving first twenty

using this Query 
select * from(SELECT  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY upload_time desc)) AS rowNum,* 
FROM [upload_news])as temp where temp.rowNum >20

please tell me if it worked